# Is there a name for this "simplified" Volterra series?

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, convolution, signal-processing, nonlinear-system

Consider a nonlinear, time-invariant system of the following form:

$g(t) = \left[h_1(t) \ast f(t)^1\right] + \left[h_2(t) \ast f(t)^2\right] + \left[h_3(t) \ast f(t)^3\right] + ...$

where $\ast$ denotes convolution, and the $h_n(t)$'s are different impulse responses of the system for each power of the input signal.

This is clearly a sort of nonlinear system that's "in between" a Taylor series and a Volterra series:

1. To get a Taylor series, force the system to be memoryless by requiring the $h_n(t)$'s to be scaled delta distributions.
2. To get a Volterra series, add in additional terms where the input is being multiplied by time-shifted versions of itself.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a name for this sort of series?
2. Is there a well-known characterization of the sorts of nonlinear time-invariant systems that can be completely described by this series?
3. Does this series turn out to be useful in practical applications?
4. Does anyone have any general reference material on this series and where it fits into the nonlinear signal "landscape"?

Comment: I probably don't understand the notation; How does this equation ensure memory across time? The index of h denotes different functions and t is a timepoint in T. The function f starts recursion at superscript 2, but because g(t) only describes a state at timepoint t, there is no memory. g() returns a state for each time point t, where the state reflects different degrees of processing. To my limited understanding, this is still a Fredholm equation because the kernels remain constant.

Comment: If $h_n$ are band pass filters and $f$ removes $m$ harmonics from $f^m$ a linear combination would make sense, but convolution of IRs makes for a much harder practical case. One possible application would be convolution reverb IRs gathered from different locations (cathedral, theater, living room, etc) and applied to a signal, assuming $t$ represents a signal in discrete time. $f$ could be some kind of adaptive amplification that returns the signal at $t$ at -1.0 dB. This would result in less and less reverberation as the IRs of spaces become larger.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - this won't be memoryless unless the h(n)'s are all scaled delta distributions. If that's the case, then the whole thing reduces to a Taylor series. Otherwise, the general case is for g(t) to depend on the value of f(t) at potentially all possible values of t.

Comment: I am mathematically disabled, but would that not require that g(t) = ... f(t-1) ...?

Comment: That's what convolution is.

Comment: So if $t$ is the domain, $g$ would have memory with only a single factor $h_1(t)*f(t)^1$?

Comment: No - every term in the summation involves memory.

Comment: But $f(t)^3=f(f(f(t)))$ and does not depend on $h(t)_n$!? What do you mean by power in this context - the polynomial index or the squared amplitude for a frequency range?

Comment: $f(t)^3 = f(t) · f(t) · f(t)$; it's the third power of $f(t)$. Iterated function composition is usually written $f^3(n)$.

Comment: Thanks. That cleared up a lot of my thoughts. I am engaging in discussion because I have been having some trouble with understanding Volterra series. The time-shift you mentioned has to my understanding a causal effect on every data point > 1 in the Volterra series - but this depends on the length of the delay or "lag", usually 1. Unlike convolution, the causality has a cascading effect. I think your equation is deterministic, but lacks a carry-over effect that one would expect with memory from previous data points.

Comment: This looks like the diagonal Volterra (Hammerstein) series.